# Login to MySql using Linux terminal not responding

Tags: mysql, linux

Im trying to login to MySQL in localhost using the root username (default) with no password entering the following command:

```
mysql -u root -h localhost
```

I dont get the  'mysql>' and it does not fail so im left with the terminal letting me type but it does not execute any commands (inside or outside of mysql). I also tried using  -p and leaving the password blank and I get the same result

Comment: Is your service started?

Comment: Do you have localhost in your hosts file and is the mysql daemon running?

Comment: I input /etc/init.d/mysql status and it says uptime: 2 hours, Threads:1, Questions, 559... etc

Comment: How do I know if Daemon is running

Comment: Is this a new installation of MySQL? How was the installation performed? (via tarball, apt-get, yum, yast etc)

Answer (score 1):

Check the following (taken from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-linuxunix-excerpt/5.5/en/unix-postinstallation.html )

Use mysqladmin to verify that the server is running. The following commands provide simple tests to check whether the server is up and responding to connections:

```
shell> bin/mysqladmin version
shell> bin/mysqladmin variables
```

The output from mysqladmin version varies slightly depending on your platform and version of MySQL, but should be similar to that shown here:

```
shell> bin/mysqladmin version
mysqladmin  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.5.29, for pc-linux-gnu on i686
...
Server version          5.5.29
Protocol version        10
Connection              Localhost via UNIX socket
UNIX socket             /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
Uptime:                 14 days 5 hours 5 min 21 sec
Threads: 1  Questions: 366  Slow queries: 0
Opens: 0  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 19
Queries per second avg: 0.000
```

If you are unable to run that command then your installation is either not complete (follow the instructions starting at the top of the page ) or you do not have permission as the user to execute the mysql program.

Answer (score -1):

Faced same issue when using Git Bash. So I try to use other terminal like CMD or Power Shell, it works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).